# Getting an id function inside an object

Tags: javascript

I have defined an object which has an function inside it:

```
var anobject = {
      getId: function(id){
            document.getElementById(id);
      }
}
```

and then I put it into a variable:
`var g = anobject.getId("d")`
And I make the variable change it's innerHTML:
`g.innerHTML = "Hi there";`
But for some reason, it doesn't work

Comment: because you do not return anything.... getId returns undefined.

Comment: You're getting the id, and then not doing anything with it.  You need to return it before you can use it for anything outside the function.

Comment: What do you think `document.getElementById(id);` does?

Comment: I gather that you need a return statement :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the result of getElementByID:

```
var anobject = {
      getId: function(id){
            return document.getElementById(id);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!!

Comment: Thank you, you can mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `return` statement in your function, so you can use the value :

```
var anobject = {
      getId: function(id){
          //returning a value
          return document.getElementById(id);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the element. Change line 3 to:

`return document.getElementById(id);`

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!!